# Global variable not updating when I assign it a value within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, global-variables

I am trying to create an array based off lines in a `.txt` file using jQuery. The array is a list of answers for a game.

The console is logging an array with content the first time but an empty array the second time. Why is `answers` not updating globally?

Here is my code:

```
//create global variable answers
var answers = new Array;
//assign a value to answers from text file
$.get("wordsEn.txt", function(txt){
    answers = txt.split('\n');
    console.log(answers);
});
console.log(answers);
```

Comment: The call to the function does not happen synchronously, so it has not yet been updated when you log.

Comment: actually, it will log empty array the first time and the content on the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call a function insite the synchronously function somthing like

```
    //create global variable answers
var answers = new Array;
var cb = function(){
    console.log(answers);
};
//assign a value to answers from text file
$.get("wordsEn.txt", function(txt){
    answers = txt.split('\n');
    console.log(answers);
    if(cb)
        cb();
});
```

Comment: Since `console.log()` is not all I want to do (there is an entire game based off the creation of that variable) do I have to put all my following code inside the `$.get()` function?

Comment: yes, you should put all the code in the $.get() or call a function inside.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log(answers);` outside the callback happens *before* the assignment.

`$.get` returns immediately, but it's callback won't necessarily be run right away; it may take a while to fetch the data.  In the meantime, the outer `console.log(answers);` is run.

Answer (score 0):

You have two calls to `console.log`, so one issue is that you can't know which one happens first because one happens synchronously and the other asynchronously. For starters, if you are debugging like this you should put some additional information in your log statement:

```
console.log('1: ' + answers);
console.log('2: ' + answers);
```

That way when you see the output you'll know if 2 happened first, or 1 happened first.

Like others have said, the inner function used in the `$.get` code happens asynchronously, which means it will run **after** the ajax request completes, which could be quick or slow sometimes, you have no way to know.